# How to create ajax request to function and return in same file with DataTable and Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

I'm new to Codeigniter and still trying to understand how its work, I'm trying to send ajax from view addHistory to the function fetchDriversHistory in controller Drivers.php
but I'm not getting a response, I'm getting an error

```
DataTables warning: table id=manageTable1 - Invalid JSON response
```

in a browser->network when I check the response of the request is a returning HTML format of the page for some reason

I have file application\views\drivers\addHistory.php that initializes the datatable

```
 manageTable = $('#manageTable1').DataTable({
 "ajax": {
  "url": "fetchDriversHistory",
  "data": {
       "user_id": <?php echo $id ?>
   }
   },
     'order': []
   });
```

in application\controllers\Drivers.php is locate fetchDriversHistory

```
 public function fetchDriversHistory()
 {
   $result = array('data' => array());

   $data = $this->model_drivers->fetchDriversHistory($id);

   foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

     $result['data'][$key] = array(
       $value['date_added'],
       $value['daily_rate'],
       $value['dayoff']
     );
   }
   echo json_encode($result);
 }
```

Model
application\models\Model_drivers.php

```
    public function fetchDriversHistory($id = null)
{
        $sql = "SELECT driver_id, daily_date, dayoff, date_added FROM addDriverHistory where id = ?";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($id));
        return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: View the raw response in your browser's network inspector.  There's probably a PHP error being thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You URL defining in javascript is wrong. 
By default, you need to define URL as `https//:<domain.com>/<controller>/<method>/<arguments>`.

For more deatil [read this](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html).

```
manageTable = $('#manageTable1').DataTable({
 "ajax": {
  "url": "<?php echo base_url('drivers/fetchDriversHistory');?>", // This will generate absulote URL
  "data": {
       "user_id": <?php echo $id ?>
   }
   },
     'order': []
   });
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is wrong, you should :

```
"url": "<?= base_url("your_controller_name/fetchDriversHistory") ?>"
```

And in addHistory.php, you send data with post name "user_id". But, in Drivers.php that post name doesn't exist